# separate output data in c language

Tags: c

I just want to ask about how to separate output data in c language, my data code is defined as machine code data , I have used WORD instruction for 4 byte.

```
      typedef uint32_t REGISTER;        // registers are 32 bits
      typedef uint32_t WORD;            // words are 32 bits
      typedef uint8_t BYTE;             // bytes are 8 bits
```

my out put is:

```
      E3A00001     MOV r0,#1
      E3A01002     MOV r1,#2
      E0802001     ADD r2,r0,r1
      E2822005     ADD r2,r2,#5
```

And I want to separate them like this:

```
       E3 A0 00 01       MOV r0,#1
       E3 A0 10 02       MOV r1,#2
       E0 80 20 01       ADD r2,r0,r1
       E2 82 20 05       ADD r2,r2,#5
```

Comment: You are an assembler developer and you ask about this?

Comment: @MartinJames you are right.acually I got confused with that, I have tried many ways but it did not  worked for me.

Comment: Do you want to split string "E3A00001" to "E3 A0 00 01"? I can't figure out what do you want

Comment: @Schullz yes please that is exactly what l need, thank you.

Comment: Where is your C code that outputs this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass read line to sprintf to get the converted string:

```
 sprintf (converted, "%c%c %c%c %c%c %c%c%s",line [0],line [1],line [2],line [3],line [4],line [5],line [6],line [7], &line [8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems quite ugly, but it does work. Anyway, 8 characters per line isn't a great number, so I think it make sense to do this job "manually".

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    fin = fopen("in.asm", "r");
    fout = fopen("out.asm", "w");
    char word[8];
    char str[80];
    while(fscanf(fin, " %c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%[^\n]", &word[0], &word[1], &word[2], &word[3], &word[4], &word[5], &word[6], &word[7], str) == 9)
    {
        fprintf(fout, "%c%c %c%c %c%c %c%c\t%s\n", word[0], word[1], word[2], word[3], word[4], word[5], word[6], word[7], str);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but my data is in string.

Comment: @Rezan Then you can simply change `fscanf()` and `fprintf() to `sscanf()` and `sprintf()`